# How To Turn A Phone Number (or area code) Into a Time Zone In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

We have software that displays phone numbers, and we need to dynamically show what time it is at that phone number. Clearly the system wont be perfect because of portability with cell phones, but its important we can approximate. Is there a library or api that does this with rails? Or at worst a simple text database we can download and use?

Answer (score 2):

You can download a database from [NANPA](http://www.nanpa.com/area_codes/index.html) which gives Country, State/Province, etc. from which you should be able to map timezone pretty easily.   NANPA administers the area code assignments, so the database should be authoritative.

Comment: There is all sorts of other geeky info on that site -- for example which "555" numbers are "Reserved for fictitious use"

Comment: Now why on earth would NANPA give the database download in MS Access MDB format!!?? Arrgh.